# Internal service traffic prioritization in kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, istio, rate-limiting

I have two classes of consumers of a service: `dev-consumers` and `prod-consumers`.  They both consume a service, `s`, which is a StatefulSet.  Scaling `s` is possible, but it takes around 20 hours to get an extra replica ready.

I want **`prod-consumers` to always be prioritized over `dev-consumers`** when using the service `s`.  The request rate from `prod-consumers` is maybe around 50-100 req/s on some days, and only 1 req/s on other days.  When `prod-consumers` is not doing a lot of requests, I want `dev-consumers` to get the rest of the available capacity.

This is probably a pretty common setup for many systems, so let me list some non-solutions I have found:

- Splitting `s` into dedicated services for prod and dev.  This has significantly higher cost, and leaves lots of capacity unused.
- I have found a [token bucket-based local rate limit](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/#local-rate-limit) in istio.  This could be a building block, but the token bucket would have to be modified manually.
- Similarly, the (typically built-in/default) nginx ingress controller supports [rate limiting through annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rate-limiting), but this is for ingresses.  There might be a way to setup this for use internally in k8s.  It would have the same downsides as the istio-system, but maybe without having to use a service mesh?

What I don't understand is this:  If a service mesh has both rate limiting and observability, it has everything needed to do traffic prioritization.  It knows how much traffic is flowing from `prod-consumers` to `s`, and if it uses token bucket based rate limiting, it could adjust these buckets based on what is observed.

Thus, I am assuming that I am missing something.  Someone, somewhere, must have a solution to this where traffic can be prioritized dynamically, as all the pieces seem to be available.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.